React Native Text Not Showing
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

interface AvatarProps {
  fullName: string;
  membership: string;
}

export default class Avatar extends Component<AvatarProps> {
  render() {
    const { fullName, membership } = this.props;

    return (
      <View style={styles.profileBar}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: './test.png'}} />
            <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.fullName}>{fullName}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.membership}>{membership}</Text>
            </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    profileBar: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      alignItems: 'center',
      padding: 10,
      gap: 7,
    },
    image: {
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
        borderRadius: 50,
    },
    textContainer: {
        marginLeft: 10,
        flex: 1,
    },
    fullName: {
        fontSize: 18,
        color: '#F2F2F2',
    },
    membership: {
        fontSize: 14,
        color: '#DEDEDE',
    },
});

In this Code i can't see the my fullname and membership. When i remove this styles
profileBar: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      alignItems: 'center',
      padding: 10,
      gap: 7,
    },
    image: {
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
        borderRadius: 50,
    },

i can see fullname and membership text. What is the problem ? Not Forgot All Components is typescript component. Every other components normally worked. Just this component get this bug.

it's not a bug, it's a feature, while you use flex row then probably your text is located righter your image, try to change flex to column -> text will appear below image,

You need to remove the flex: 1 from textContainer on styles:
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  profileBar: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 10,
    gap: 7,
  },
  image: {
      width: 40,
      height: 40,
      borderRadius: 20,
  },
  textContainer: {
      marginLeft: 10,
      // flex: 1,
  },
  fullName: {
      fontSize: 18,
      color: '#F2F2F2',
  },
  membership: {
      fontSize: 14,
      color: '#DEDEDE',
  },
});

You can see the full example on this Expo Snack.

Text not showing again

Could you talk about exactly what want you to do? I don't understand why you want to remove the profileBar and image styles. Could you share your code by Expo Snack?

i dont understand. Everything is okay in the snack but i cant see the texts in the expo go (virtual device and my phone)
https://snack.expo.dev/zclZaUdhrYa3ey-IX7Ikb

I cloned your Expo Snack and made some changes, check it. I removed the <View /> that's wrapping the <AccountBar /> from file Home.tsx and commented the line with flex: 1 from textContainer style like the code on the answer above.

@ShahinBabayev, did it work for you? Do you have any questions or problems about it?
